# Is it possible to fake Useragent in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, web-crawler

I want to create a crawler with C#. The problem is that some websites have disabled black listed crawlers in their *robots.txt* file, using:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Is there a way I could fake my request to show that I'm for instance Googlebot?

Comment: Stinks for miles. What is this for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`HttpWebRequest` has `.UserAgent`, however - I would simply say: don't.

Of course, your point re robots.txt is rather moot; that is for **you** to follow. If you write a badly behaved tool that ignores `robots.txt` **regardless** of what you claim as your user-agent, then you should expect to be blacklisted fairly quickly.

In particular, trying to impersonate any of the major players is very dubious. Frankly I'd expect most major sites to also check the incoming IP range.

Comment: I could create a crawler that uses a webbrowser to get the info I want. I need the website's data for a data mining project. No intention of abusing anything ;)

Comment: @AlirezaNoori my point is: if a site cares enough to issue different robots.txt rules to different agents, then they probably aren't going to trust you that you are google

Comment: Well, actually turns out, they just wanted me to have a Useragent. I set my own program's name to the property and it worked. No need to set it to the Googlebot. Win-win :D

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the HttpWebRequest has a property for user agent. You can set that to anything.